# need help in sql query with counting values within dates

Tags: php, mysql

the table:

tab_tasks

```
id|....|date_completed|completed
1 |    |  2016-11-05  |   Y
2 |    |  2016-11-07  |   N
3 |    |  2016-11-09  |   Y
4 |    |  2016-12-11  |   Y
5 |    |  2017-01-15  |   Y
6 |    |  2017-01-30  |   Y
```

and so on...

I need help in writing sql query by giving current date and get months with counted completed tasks back to max 12 months something like:

```
month        | num_complited
november     |     2
december     |     1
january      |     2
```

or if it would be easier the instead of letters of the alphabet, month can be numeric 11, 12, 01 in column month.

How can be this accomplished? Is there a need for any php code or can be this done with just sql query? Or should I add extra column to that table, like month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should put some date range otherwise  for example 11-2016 has 6 count  and 11-2017 has 5 so out put will show 11 count  data mix-up

```
 SELECT MONTHNAME(date_completed) as month ,
  count(completed)  as num_complited 
  from tab_tasks 
  where completed='Y' and 
  date_completed between '2016-11-05'  and '2017-11-05' 
  group by MONTHNAME(date_completed)
```

Comment: this answer seems to be what I'd need, but I don't know why I get empty result if I add your date range?  (of course my records are in that date range) When I remove the date condition then shows fine, any idea?

Comment: may be you try like  '2016-11-05'

Comment: can you try now I have added single quotas

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select MONTHNAME(date_completed) as MosName,count(1) as num_completed  
from TableName
where completed = 'Y'
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(date_completed);
```

Comment: you forget to add from table